# How to open the another web page without changing the current page on Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've written below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
driver.get('https://www.yahoo.com/')
```

Of course this code just shows the 2nd page, but I want to show both of the pages at the same time. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two separate `webdriver.Chrome` instances:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver1.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
driver2.get('https://www.yahoo.com/')
```